# Click action going through top most view

Tags: android

I have this button that I have manually positioned at the bottom of the screen (I intentionally made it semi transparent so we can see the issue), over a `BottomNavigationView`.

[image]

I do this through this code:

```
val buttonFinalHeight = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.fullwidthbutton_height)
        val screenHeight = context.displaySize().height
        val rootPanelYLocation = root_filtersheet_panel.locationOnScreen().y
        filter_gobutton.y = (screenHeight-rootPanelYLocation).toFloat()
```

That is, I manually set the Y coordinate of the view so I can position it at the bottom. The reason is that this Button belongs to a fragment that is positioned on top of the `BottomNavigationView`, but this button needs to be at the bottom of the screen, over any other views (including the bottom menu).

That means every layout containing this button has `clipChildren=false` so the button can overflow.

As you can see in the screenshot it works. However when I try to click on it the touch action is passed on to the bottomnavigationview instead to my button, as demonstrated by this ripple:

[image]

Now the button does accept click actions as demonstrated by this other screencap where I clicked in the topmost region that goes above the BottomNavigationMenu, again proven by the ripple effect on the button itself:

[image]

I have tried setting an onTouchListener on my button and playing with elevation numbers (BNV has 0 elevation, button has 16, but no change), but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: I fear there's nothing as `z-index` for android :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modeling the button as a Dialog. Not the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the click listeners for the buttons below. And add them again when the fragment is closed.

Comment: I thought about this but I feel that touch actions should somehow be aligned with the draw order/render?

Comment: @GabrielSanmartin I feel that they should not overlap as well. What about removing the views from the layout when opening the fragment?

Comment: Ok so I disabled the menu options and now they are not clickable, however my button is also not clickable!